# initialise a var in scala

Tags: scala

I have a class where I like to initialize my var by reading a configfile, which produces intermediate objects/vals, which I would like to group and hide in a method. 
Here is the bare minimum of the problem - I call the ctor with a param i, in reality a File to parse, and the init-method generates the String s, in reality more complicated than here, with a lot of intermediate objects being created:

```
class Foo (val i: Int) {

    var s : String;

    def init () {
        s = "" + i 
    }

    init ()
}
```

This will produce the error: `class Foo needs to be abstract, since variable s is not defined`. In this example it is easy to solve by setting the String to "": `var s = "";`, but in reality the object is more complex than String, without an apropriate Null-implementation.

I know, I can use an Option, which works for more complicated things than String too:

```
var s : Option [String] = None

def init () {
    s = Some ("" + i) 
}
```

or I can dispense with my methodcall. Using an Option will force me to write Some over and over again, without much benefit, since there is no need for a None else than to initialize it that way I thought I could.

Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: So, in Scala, you can never declare a `var s : String` and then initialize it in  some other method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of creating separate methods for initialization, you should perform the initialization using the following way :

```
class Foo(val i: Int) {
  var s: String = {
    var s0 = " "
    s0 += i
    // do some more stuff with s0
    s0
  }

  var dashedDate = {
    val dashed = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd")
    dashed.format(updated)
  }

  // Initializing more than one field:
  var (x, y, z) = {
    var x0, y0, z0 = 0
    // some calculations
    (x0, y0, z0)
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't commit my comment, yesterday? Well, now that I see it, your answer with a tuple in a block looks so obvious. I like it.

Answer (score 19):

`var s : Whatever = _` will initialize s to the default value for Whatever (null for reference types, 0 for numbers, false for bools etc.)

Comment: This doesn't work for List[List[Int]] = _ , it throws runtime exception. Why?

Comment: @user2441441 As I said, the default value for reference types is null. So if the runtime exception you're talking about is a null pointer exception, that means you used the variable without assigning it a non-null value first.

Comment: @Sepp2k Sorry, it doesn't throw a null pointer, it throws a Error: local variables must be initialized
   var abc: List[List[Int]] = _
...and when it's assigned to null it throws null pointer like you said -> In this case I'm using the variable to add Int to the list

Comment: @user2441441 That's not a runtime exception, that's a compilation error. Anyway, you can't initialize local variables with `_`. If you want them to be null, you'll have to explicitly initialize them to be `null`. And if you don't want them to be `null`, you'll have to initialize them to whatever else you do want them to be.

Comment: @sepp2k I see, so when a local var List variable is initialized to null(assuming we are not using Options), we need a if/else stmt like java for a null check? Or the only other option is to initialize it to an initial value(non-empty) if we want to avoid the if/else null check?

Comment: @user2441441 That really depends on what you're trying to do. Initializing instance variables to `null` instead of using options can make sense if you know that the variable will always be set to a non-null value before it is used (e.g. if the method that sets it is always be called before the one that uses it). In that case you don't need a null check and using options would lead to unnecessary code. That situation doesn't really apply to local variables. If you're in a situation where there might not be a value for a given variable, you should use options.

Comment: @user2441441 You could use null checks like in Java, but that would not be idiomatic. That's exactly what options are meant for. If you're in a situation where you know that the variable will be assigned a proper value before it's used, but for some reason you can't assign it that value right away, then using `null` is a valid option (though as I said, that kind of situation should be quite rare with local variables). In that case there's no need for null checks. A null pointer exception would only happen if your initial assumption was wrong and in that case you'd want to know.

Comment: @Sepp2k Okay, I was asking because in LeetCode questions the expected method return type is not wrapped in an Option, so I cannot use Options in the methods

Comment: @user2441441 Does it expect `null` as a possible return value? Because if not, it doesn't seem like you should be using either. Not as the return value, anyway. Of course that doesn't mean, you can't use options internally inside the method if that makes sense for your situation. I'd have to see the question and your code to give more advice than that.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, why are you using var? Why not just do:

```
val rootObject = readFile(filename)
```

This would make the most sense to me.

Comment: a) because the real object isn't a String, but mutable object. and b) there are more objects initialised by reading the file, for example an array, for which the dimensions are specified in the file, as well as the content of the array.

Comment: Why is it mutable? you're missing the point.

Also, val arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer[MyType]()

and then arrayBuffer.toArray

Comment: If it was an unmutable val, I would understand that I can't declare it in line x and initialice it in line x+n | n>0. Therefore I mentioned that it is a var, not a val.